# jQuery change event after setting value via document.getElementById(...).value

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, jquery-events

I'm trying to handle change event, but it seems it doesn't work. I would like to handle the event using jQuery after setting value via `document.getElementById('id_of_input').value`. Here is the code: http://jsbin.com/axagej (to edit see: http://jsbin.com/axagej/edit) - I would like to see an alert.

Comment: Someone came through and down-voted the question and both answers, with no comment. Helpful, no?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're setting the value programatically you need to fire the event yourself using [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) or [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$("#sample").change();
```

or

```
$("#sample").trigger("change");
```

Comment: Really? Ehh... So I'll use watch(). Thanks for response! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The change event is working fine for me. It's just acting when you lost focus. If you prefer alert while writing, you should be interested by the jQuery keyboard events (http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/).

@tchaOo

Comment: I think poster is referring to the fact that the change event does not fire when he sets the value to "something" programatically (via  setTimeout in this case)

Answer (score -1):

When you're programmatically changing the value of a field, you won't get a change event.  You'll need to explicitly invoke the change handler.  See the updated jsbin: http://jsbin.com/axagej/2/edit